# C++ code doesn't work in geany

Tags: c++, g++, geany

I'm trying geany to run my c++ program but it doesn't work. An error saying "g++ is not recognized an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" comes when built. What i have missed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you don't have g++ installed on your computer. Open Terminal and write : `sudo apt-get install g++` (assuming you are working on linux)

Comment: http://www.geany.org/Support/RunningOnWindows .Checkout this webpage. At the bottom page it redirects you to a webpage where you can install it.

Comment: What if gcc and g++ are installed and runnable in a normal terminal but Geany is still unable to find them? When running the build command and typing "g++" directly into the Geany Terminal at the bottom, the result is:  
[ org.geany.Geany ~]$ g++
sh: g++: command not found